# How can I add the CopyWebpackPlugin to create-react-app without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I am building a react application and **I want to copy all image files from the source destination to the build destination**. I am following some tutorials and so far managed to use `react-app-wired` and the `CopyWebpackPlugin`

I am getting no errors and no files are being copied.

This is my `config-overrides.js`

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
   if (!config.plugins) {
    config.plugins = [];
  }
  config.plugins.push(
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      {
        from: 'src/images',
        to: 'public/images'
      }
    ])
  );
  return config;
};
```

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "public",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.5.2",
    "react-axios": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typeface-montserrat": "0.0.54",
    "webfontloader": "^1.6.28"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-app-rewired start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-app-rewired build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.22.1"
  }
}
```

My folder structure is

`src/images
src/images/file.jpg
src/images/slider/1.png
src/images/slider/2.png
public/images (empty) so far`

Comment: Simply you may have to do something like in https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app advanced guides

Comment: Questions:1. Do you need to use webpack plugin for this? can you not add a script to `build` in package.json? 2. Are you using CRA or react-app-rewired? Question title says CRA, but code says `react-app-rewired`. 3. CRA should put all the images by default in `build/static/media` does that path not work for you?

Comment: Just watched a video tutorial a few days back, maybe this can help(not sure if you'll need a membership for watching this)?
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-customize-create-react-app-cra-without-ejecting-using-react-app-rewired

Comment: @dubes I think you need to do `import image1 from './component/file.jpg` in order for that to work and that it compressed and attaches a random name to it

Comment: I've found it much easier to deal with config idiosyncrasies like this after ejecting the project from `create-react-app`, so that actually may be the best way to go. `create-react-app` is only intended as a starting point, not as the canonical React configuration for the project throughout its entire life.

Comment: Central upstream discussion for custom configs in general appears to be at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6303 BTW.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you just want to move files from `-/src/<somewhere>` to `./<somewhereElse>` at *build* time.

You could just add an extra step to your `build` script in package.json. The step below is completely in your control and does not mess with any create-react-app scripts or configuration.

For example, I used the `ncp` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp), but if you want more granular control, you can also create your own "step" with ncp or even with raw node fs api.

Here is a way to replicate what I did:

**Setup**

```
npx create-react-app img-upload
cd img-upload/
yarn add --dev ncp
```

**Test Data**
create src/images/ folder structure and put in files

```
ls -R src/images/
src/images/:
badge.jpg  folder1

src/images/folder1:
applause.gif  blank.png
```

**Package.json**

I only edited the part: `"build": "ncp './src/images' './public/images' &&  react-scripts build",`

```
{
  "name": "img-upload",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "ncp './src/images' './public/images' &&  react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ncp": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

**Test:** 
Before running build:

```
ls public
favicon.ico  index.html  manifest.json
```

After running build: `yarn build`

```
ls public
favicon.ico  images  index.html  manifest.json

ls -R public/images
public/images/:
badge.jpg  folder1

public/images/folder1:
applause.gif  blank.png

ls build
asset-manifest.json  favicon.ico  images  index.html  manifest.json  service-worker.js  static

ls -R build/images
build/images/:
badge.jpg  folder1

build/images/folder1:
applause.gif  blank.png
```

**Suggestion**
I am assuming you ultimately need these files in `build` directory. If so, you can just switch your `build` script.

```
"build": "react-scripts build && ncp './src/images' './build/images'",
```

That way you won't pollute your public folder, which you may want to keep in your source control.

Comment: I ended up adding this in `start` and `build` but I did `"ncp": "ncp src/images public/images"` and just added `ncp` as a reference. Is there any way to watch the folder during development? Otherwise I have to kill node each time and run `npm start` or `npm build`

Comment: I've a few ideas, but it depends  on what you're trying to achieve. I'll need to understand your flow a bit more. Let's try and start a chat tomorrow.

Comment: Just a way that npm will watch and always copy to the image folder making sure if I rename, it renames, if I delete, it deletes - complete sync real time watch

Comment: I'm looking for ways that can be done. One other train of thought: Can you not keep them in the public folder alone? How are you importing these images in your react component?

Comment: I am just using `<img src='/images/file.jpg'/>` before I was writing them as `import` but when you have huge sliders or big image content then I decided to directly call them. I also have an axios JSON API which links the images like inside of those variables and objects

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely not recommended to modify the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js` file as this will break when this particular package is updated. Also most probably you would be having `node_modules` ignored in your version control system, meaning this config wont be shared across developers or backed up.

Although I haven't tried myself personally you could use something like this : https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired to override the Webpack config.

You can have a look at the tutorial here : https://medium.com/@timarney/but-i-dont-wanna-eject-3e3da5826e39

Comment: Thanks for the answer so far, I updated my question and so far managed to get the plugin architecture and file prep ready but no files being copied or errors being produced.

Answer (score 5):

Mine worked like this:

```
const { override, addWebpackPlugin } = require('customize-cra');
module.exports = {
webpack: override(
    addWebpackPlugin(
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'src/config', to: 'config' }
            ],
        })
    )
)
```

With that, I'm taking the contents of my config folder and creating an equal one in the build also called config.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is because you are using `webpack-dev-server` together with `copy-webpack-plugin`. If that's true, the `copy-webpack-plugin` will copy files to virtual directory which `webpack-dev-server` works. So that, In this situation, you need to add one more plugin to make it happen

> If you want webpack-dev-server to write files to the output directory
>   during development, you can force it with the
>   write-file-webpack-plugin.

```
import WriteFilePlugin from 'write-file-webpack-plugin';
```

webpack config:

```
config.plugins.push(
    new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      {
        from: 'src/images',
        to: 'public/images'
      }
    ])
  );
config.plugins.push(new WriteFilePlugin());
```

You can visit the official document for more information: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/

Hope this works!